# Statement.executeUpdate() returns 0 even though the target database records is observed to be updated

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using an existing program to update a given column, however, whenever I run the `statement.executeUpdate()`, I always get the result as 0.

Example code:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
int result = stmt.executeUpdate("update emp set salary = 100 where emp_id = '"+empId+ "' ");

System.out.println(result);
```

Structure of `emp` table:

```
salary number(5,2)
emp_id varchar2(50)
```

Before update:

```
Emp_Id  Salary
E123        20
```

After update:

```
Emp_Id  Salary
E123          100
```

And result is 0.

This is just a sample table, but I am facing this issue.

What am I missing out on? I am using ojdbc6.jar and use jdbc thin driver.

Comment: Your question title refers to `executeUpdate`, but your code has `executeQuery`... which returns a result set rather than a number. Which are you really using?

Comment: Your before-and-after data is also for different IDs; and your statement isn't enclosing the ID string in single quotes. (Though you should be using bind variables anyway). It would be helpful if you showed real code and data, to demonstrate what is actually happening - at the moment we can't tell if you're just looking at the wrong data, for instance. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Alex Poole, apologises, the query was regarding executeUpdate()

Comment: Alex, apologies again, typing mistake for before and after data. This is just an example I tried to debug the issue, but in vain, hence copy-pasted that code here.

Comment: this code seems vulnerable to SQL injection due to using the explicit SQL statement. Rather you may use a package, procedure, class, function .. etc instead.